# .NET 4.5.1 Track all Tasks for Cancellation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, appdomain, cancellation-token

5 unrelated class instances do Task.Run() to start 1-4 instances that "do stuff". Each Task has a CancellationToken. What is a cool or smart way to have another object stop all of those spawned Tasks without touching/affecting their spawning objects? If this was the .NET 2.0 days I might start things in another AppDomain and then kill the AppDomain to stop the child work, or something similar. It also occurred to me that the child Task might check a static class on a Timer interval to see if it should stop, but I want to keep the responsibility out of the spawned Tasks if possible.

Comment: Why not run them all on one cancellation token?

Answer (score 1):

If possible and/or applicable, use the same `CancellationToken` for each of the tasks, and just request cancellation via the `CancellationTokenSource`. If each task has its own `CancellationToken` to support individual cancellation, you can use the following strategy instead:

1. Create a `CancellationTokenSource` instance which you can use to issue a cancel request to all tasks.
2. When you start your tasks, start each with a [`CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642265.aspx) that provides you with a `CancellationToken` that enters the canceled state as soon as any of the inputs is canceled.

This allows you to preserve the original individual cancellation support as well as use a `CancellationTokenSource` for global cancellation.